# Using forms in tests

Tags: c#, winforms, mstest

I have an integration test that makes a form appear. It is not a coded UI test, it is just a test that happens to use a form. Lets not discuss now, that in general it is a good idea or not, it is in my case necessary.

If everything runs in order, then the form appears, some functions are called, the form is closed, assertions are made, and the unit test passes.

But, if something goes wrong ...

If an exception occures then instead of a failing unit test I got the "Unhadled exception occurred" dialog. This dialog of course stops the application, until somone clicks "ok" (and there is no one to click "ok" on a CI server), and after that the test passes. (Or at least it is marked green.)

The question is, how can I change back this behaviour?

After some research, I have found out, that there are [2 top level exception handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), one for the application, and one for the UI thread.

I set them like this:

```
    Application.ThreadException += (o, e) => MessageBox.Show("hello ui thread");

    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (o, e) => MessageBox.Show("hello app");
```

Then, when an exception occurres, I get the "hello ui thread" messagebox.

Can I set the `Application.ThreadException` in a way, that it restores the original behaviour? Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**

As some answerers pointed out I have a piece of **really bad code** in my hands, there is nothing to deny about it. Believe me, the fact thet the UI and the business logic in not adequately seperated is far not the worst thing about it.

I am not here to make excuses, but I can honestly state that it is not my fault. This piece of code was written by someone I have never met, and does not work at my company anymore. (For a damn good reason.)

There is no adequate documentation nor specification about what this code does, but it is sadly an important part of the software, we can't afford breaking it, or make it any more broken than it is now.

I have to refactor it, yes. I ****am**** refactoring it. But for that I need to write some tests first. And to write some test, I need do refactor it. It is the case of the egg and the chicken.

Right now I do not need general advice about good software design. I do not need judgement about the situation I am in. I need a specific technical answer to a specific technical question I asked.

**OFF**

About the "if you were one of my developers" comment. I think you would be **really glad** to have a developer who cleans up the mess that someone else made.

Comment: What behaviour *do* you want if an exception occurs? What original behaviour are you talking about? At this point the test *has* failed. If a client was using your application the application would have crashed with the very message you posted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No it doesn't: it hangs until someone clicks "ok". I added a sentence to clarify this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The original behaviour is that the test fails, and is marked red. The behaviour I have insted is that the "Unhanlded exception occurred" and the test hangs.

Comment: You mix up different things. When a UI application fails, the OS will display a dialog box. *That* is the original behavior. If you want to change this you need to handle unhandled exceptions. If you want your tests to be able to handle such crashes, either create a coded UI test, or add a timeout to the test to mark it as failed. You'll have to do that anyway if your unhandled exception handler displays its own dialog boxes

Comment: It's not clear what the original behavior was,  in the question, you said the original result was that the unhandled exception dialog came up and then test ended up green.  In the comments you say that the test went through and had a red result.

Comment: @SteveMitcham In a normal case, if an exception occurres in a test, the test failes. That is what I mean by original. The behaviour I have, but do not want, is that the error message window appears and it makes the test hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this peice of code I can rethrow the exception from the UI thread on the main thread:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
  Exception thread_ex = null;
  ThreadExceptionEventHandler eventHandler = (o, e) =>
  {
    thread_ex = e.Exception;  //store the exception from the UI thread
    Application.ExitThread(); //kill the UI thread
  };

  Application.ThreadException += eventHandler;

  DoTest();                   //do the test

  Application.ThreadException -= eventHandler;

  if (thread_ex != null)      //if an exception was stored
    throw thread_ex;          //throw it again on the main thread
}
```

Because I use the `Application.ThreadException`, the "Unhandled exception occurred" dialog will not appear.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution for your issue.  I'm unfamiliar with the way mstest does things, but since Application is a static, should you remove your event handler before you leave the test?

Answer (score 1):

Running any type of UI test on a CI server is not a good idea because of the exact behavior that you are seeing.  Changing production code to suit your tests is not a good idea either.

If I were in this situation I would do two things.  First, I would refactor the code to ensure that as much of the functionality of the form could be driven without the UI in the form of standard unit tests.  This could be in the form of a presenter, controller or view model of some kind.

Second, I would remove the integration test that uses the actual form from the CI suite and only run it manually as part of a final integration suite that ensures that the view model is wired correctly.

In your case, if you set up your logic module such that if all the tests pass the form test won't throw any exceptions, then you can go ahead and run your tests at this point if you set up your form test to not run if the previous tests fail.

Comment: This is a very bad answer. 1: You did not answer the question. 2: I explicitly wrote "Lets not discuss now, that in general it is a good idea or not, it is in my case necessary."

Comment: Actually, this is the only realistic answer. You *must* discuss the decisions that made your code hard to test. Getting a *unit* test framework to understand OS dialog boxes is more difficult than fixing the original problems

Comment: You don't have to accept the answer, and I understand that it may not be what you want to hear, or would solve your immediate issue.  However, if one of my developers came to me with this question, this is the answer I would give and others may come to this question with a similar situation and my advice will be here.

Comment: @SteveMitcham I do see your point, and understand why you wrote what you wrote. See the update in the question.